# PHP Warning: Xdebug MUST be loaded as a Zend extension

Tags: php, linux, cpanel

Here's the error I'm getting:

```
PHP Warning:  Xdebug MUST be loaded as a Zend extension in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  Module 'xdebug' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
```

This is from my php.ini file:

```
; Directory in which the loadable extensions (modules) reside.
extension_dir = "/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626"
zend_extension="/usr/local/IonCube/ioncube_loader_lin_5.3.so"
extension=xdebug.so
zend_extension="xdebug.so"
```

The file `xdebug.so` does exist at `/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626`

I haven't made any changes and my server has a fresh install of cPanel.  Anyone know what would be causing this to happen or see any issues with the information above?

Comment: Try to comment `extension=xdebug.so`

Comment: Did none of the search results for [Xdebug MUST be loaded as a Zend extension](https://www.google.com/search?q=Xdebug+MUST+be+loaded+as+a+Zend+extension) help you?

Comment: Just tried that and the error message changed to this `Failed loading xdebug.so:  xdebug.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`

Comment: @lxg I've looked through those suggestions, but most are telling you to just look to make sure it exists and in my case it is looking in the correct directory...

Answer (score 27, accepted):

For anyone else who is having this issue, I updated this in my php.ini file and it fixed the error:

```
; Directory in which the loadable extensions (modules) reside.
extension_dir = "/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626"
zend_extension = "/usr/local/IonCube/ioncube_loader_lin_5.3.so"
zend_extension = "/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626/xdebug.so"
extension = "pdo.so"
extension = "pdo_sqlite.so"
extension = "pdo_mysql.so"
extension = "sqlite.so"
```

Comment: Only module extensions (those installed with extension=) are found within the extension_dir path. Engine extensions (installed with zend_extension) should use an absolute path.

Comment: This answer helped me. My issues was that I included xdebug as 'extension' prior, and again as 'zend_extension'. So just commenting 'extension' load fixed this issue

Answer (score 31):

Just switch `extension` to `zend_extension` in your active *php.ini* file.

Comment: I didn't even know this was a thing. Worked for me on Apache with PHP 7.3.8 on Windows 10. Thank you :)

Answer (score 7):

The problem is the way IIS adds the extension related configuration to the php.ini file. To solve the problem simple replace in php.ini file,

```
extension=php_xdebug-2.5.0rc1-7.0-vc14-nts-x86_64.dll
```

with

```
zend_extension=php_xdebug-2.5.0rc1-7.0-vc14-nts-x86_64.dll
```

Although now IIS might not recognize xdebug extension as enabled, it is enabled and can be verified by checking the phpinfo() results.

Answer (score 0):

First: verify that the output phpize is exactly the same the web /wizar show you.

Verify, after getting phpinfo() that xdebug had been installed correctly. Ctrl + f: xdebug. If not, go for the documentation https://xdebug.org/docs/install#configure-php and how to install using the console on your php verion.

Answer (score -1):

For those who have windows, just change the file by the location of the file where the extension is

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).